# Is it possible to call all while also finding id in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I wish to display the name of the category in the title section however I can't seem to call the specific Category::find($id) since I also have Category::all(). It works, however I can't display the category name.

Here's my code.
Controller

```
public function categorized($id)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $businesses = Business::where('category_id', $category->id)->get()->sortBy('name');
    if (Auth::check()) {
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $users = User::where('id', $userId)->get();

    return view('directories.categorized', [
        'categories' => $categories,
        'businesses' => $businesses,
        'users' => $users,
        ]);
    } else {
        return view('directories.categorized', [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'businesses' => $businesses,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', "$categories")

@section('content')
<div style="margin-top: 40px;">
    @foreach ($businesses as $business)
    <a href='{{ url("/businessprofile/$business->id/".Str::slug($business->name)) }}'>
        <img src='{{ asset("storage/$business->logo") }}'>
        <h5>{{ $business->name }}</h5>
    </a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

@endsection

If I put $categories->name it says that the name property is not found but if put foreach it simply gives the first data in categories table.

While $categories, it just returns the array of my categories table

Comment: $categories->name does not work when you get data using $categories = Category::all();
It's a collection of categories object if you use $categories[index]->name then It would be work

Comment: it doesnt work. it says undefined index: index

Answer (score 1):

In you controller, return view with category.
`'category' => Category::find($id)`

I don't know if you need all categories, but at least, you should pass one.

In blade view, call `$category->name`.

Comment: Hi! yes I do need to call Category::all() because I have @include('layouts.verticalNav') in my app.blade.php which are links to respective categories, atleast that's how I thought it should be. Or are there any ways to do it?

Comment: Ok, return all and return the category you want ti work.

Comment: Could you tell me what you have in mind? I think what I did and what you said is similar or maybe not